# Windows phone disable application bar button

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, application-bar

So, what is my problem ? I have a `popup`, and when i open it, i want to disable current page in my windows phone applications. so i make this `this.IsEnabled = false;` But my `ApplicationBar` is still available. Of course i try with:

```
ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = false;
```

My next idea was to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Count; i++)
{
    ((ApplicationBarMenuItem)ApplicationBar.Buttons[i]).IsEnabled = false;
}
```

and still no result. I'm sure that some is done that before, can you show me how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The application bar consists of a Buttons collection and MenuItems collection. For your example you would want to try something like

```
foreach (var button in ApplicationBar.Buttons)
{
    ((ApplicationBarIconButton) button).IsEnabled = false; // disables the button
}

ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = false; // this will prevent menu from opening
```

if this isn't working, have you considered hiding the App bar?
`ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;`

Answer (score 3):

How about this

```
((ApplicationBarIconButton)this.ApplicationBar.Buttons[1]).IsEnabled = true;
```

Where [1] is the index of the button you want to enable/disable

I know for a fact this works as I have code that uses it in a Windows Phone 8 app

Can you post some code for us to see please

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, according to [this post](http://www.learningwindowsphone.com/blog/?p=62) there is a bug which means that setting the `IsEnabled` property of an `ApplicationBarMenuItem` does not get honoured until the menu is closed and re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the using Microsoft.Phone.Shell to pickup the namespace within your .cs file and you can do the following:

```
ApplicationBar.Enable();
```

and

```
ApplicationBar.Disable();
```

According to http://new.efficientcoder.net/2010/10/windows-phone-7-quick-tip-17.html

Answer (score 0):

try this :

xaml:

```
<shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="False">
```

.cs

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                UIHelper.ToggleVisibility(Canvas_LocationAR_Trans);
                UIHelper.ToggleVisibility(Grid_LocARLoadingGrid);
                **ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;**
            });
```